# Spacing between elements not works right in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am using spacing for controlling the space between child elements in TailwindCSS but it not works right. See at **first image**, the first element has excess and uneven spacing, the **image 2** is what i am expected. How can i solve this?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKbRC.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofc2X.png) (my expected results)

My code not working right as my expect below:

```
          <div className="w-[400px] flex space-x-2 space-y-2 flex-wrap">
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
            <div className="w-[50px] height-[20px] bg-red-400 text-center">Box</div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I got this issue commonly using `space-y` within a flexbox, you can achieve the same thing by using `gap-2`

Comment: To further top up @MikeShiv's comment, the Tailwind CSS documentation officially discourages the use of spacing classes if you're using grid or flexbox: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#limitations

Comment: same the issue. @MikeShiv `gap-2` just working for grid.

Comment: `gap` also works with flexbox: https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox